# Is there a YouTube URL format for displaying videos in 1080p?

Tags: url, youtube

I know there is this `&hd=1` code to start a YouTube video in 720p. Is there a code or trick to add at the end of a YouTube video URL to start in 1080p?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems to be working again :)

Using an example:

before:

- `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecsCrOEYl7c`

after:

- `http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v=ecsCrOEYl7c&vq=hd1080`

note both:

- `watch_popup`
- `&vq=hd1080`

Other possible values can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality

You can also change the start time of the player by appending this (to 1 minute and 22 seconds in this example):

- `&t=1m22s`

Some documentation can be found here:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: As of Feb. 26, 2014, the following attribute `&vq=hd1080` to force HD playback when embedding a YT video works perfectly fine. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/pUkU8/

Comment: View the API reference here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_quality

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to set the quality to 1080p only with an URL. Some years ago it was possible by adding `&fmt=37` but it doesn't work anymore.

However, if you can use JavaScript the [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=fr#Playback_quality) will allow you to select the quality.

Answer (score 2):

From [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#hd):

> hd (supported players: AS2)
>
> Values: 0 or 1. Default is 0. Setting to 1 enables HD playback by default. This has no effect on the Chromeless Player. This also has no
>   effect if an HD version of the video is not available. If you enable
>   this option, keep in mind that users with a slower connection may have
>   an sub-optimal experience unless they turn off HD. You should ensure
>   your player is large enough to display the video in its native
>   resolution.

AS2 player will be retired in October 2012 and the embed codes on YouTube website load AS3 player by default. To show hd1080 you need to use JavaScript API. The functions are described [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_quality).