# How to load youtube video in hd1080 in youtube player API in android?

Tags: android, youtube

i am developing one application which show youtube video in which i was used youtube player API. 
My problem is that i want to load youtube video in hd1080.

```
private void playVideoAtSelection() {

        if (player != null) {
            currentlySelectedId = pack.getURL();
            player.loadVideo(currentlySelectedId);          
        }
    }
```

Is there any function in android like java script which set resolution at load time.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704571/is-there-a-youtube-url-format-for-displaying-videos-in-1080p

Comment: this document is for java script i want for android youtube player api

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your video using the [Iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). You create a custom html file with the `<iframe>` tag, and put this file in the assets folder. Then you load this html using a WebView with a Chrome Client. This way you will be able to use the [setPlaybackQuality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#setPlaybackQuality) method. I think the youtube api for Android is not able to make this configuration.

Comment: but in Youtube application there is menu to set quality...
Can any function related to this available in android player API

Comment: Yes. You have this in the Youtube oficial app, as well as in some app you use the Android Youtube Api. The question is I don't find any way to set this programmatically as you want to do, except using the iframe.

Comment: See these questions and theis answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636057/how-to-set-to-play-only-hd-videos-in-youtube-android-player-api
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720967/video-quality-on-youtube-android-player-api
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547888/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-quality-of-the-video